# Node package that allows crawling of sites that requires javascript

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, http-post, user-agent, superagent

So i've been searching endlessly for a package that allows crawling of javascript sites. I've been trying selenium but i don't like the whole browser deal.

Is there a solution similar to *superagent* and *request* where you do post & get requests, which also has javascript "enabled"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [scraperjs](https://github.com/ruipgil/scraperjs) dynamicScraper function or [phantomjs](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs).
They both allow run js without loading whole browser.
And here an example for [how to wait for some events](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) on page